# Retrofit вылетает и выдает ошибку Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Всем привет. Я собрал модель ModelConfig. По Json. Параметр langs имеет массив из 2 объектов, мне приходит 2 запрос с langs у которого пустой массив. В итоге я получаю ошибку. Сервер сам решает когда присылать пустой массив, а когда заполенный. В любом случае ему должно быть все равно что за массив приходит. Но в итоге я получаю ошибку

> Error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line column path $.response.design.langs
```

Моя модель.

```
  public class ModelConfig {

    @SerializedName("code") public int code;
    @SerializedName("status") public String status;
    @SerializedName("response") public ResponseBean response;

    public static class ResponseBean {
        @SerializedName("portal_code") public String portalCode;
        @SerializedName("design") public DesignBean design;
        @SerializedName("portal_id") public String portalId;
        @SerializedName("appColorScheme") public AppColorSchemeBean appColorScheme;

        public static class DesignBean {
            @SerializedName("logo") public String logo;
            @SerializedName("langs") public List<String> langs;
        }

        public static class AppColorSchemeBean {
            @SerializedName("slide_menu") public String slideMenu;
            @SerializedName("slide_menu_color") public String slideMenuColor;
            @SerializedName("app_buttons") public String appButtons;
            @SerializedName("app_buttons_color") public String appButtonsColor;
        }
    }
}
```

---

вот так выглядит текущий Json.

**Если приходит такой Json ошибок НЕТ.

```
  {
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "response": {
        "design": {
            "logo": "logo-en.png",
            "favicon": "favicon.ico",
            "langs": {
                "logo-en": "logo-en.png",
                "logo-ar": "logo-ar.png"
            }
        },
        "appColorScheme": {
            "slide_menu": "#f3f4f3",
            "slide_menu_color": "#454545",
            "app_buttons": "#280091",
            "app_buttons_color": "#ffffff"
        }
    }
}
```

**ЕСЛИ ПРИХОДИТ ТАКОЙ JSON Без langs то я получаю ошибку

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "response": {
        "design": {
            "logo": "logo-en.png",
            "favicon": "favicon.ico",
            "langs": { }
        },
        "appColorScheme": {
            "slide_menu": "#f3f4f3",
            "slide_menu_color": "#454545",
            "app_buttons": "#280091",
            "app_buttons_color": "#ffffff"
        }
    }
}
```

Код который использую из этой модели

```
   Constants.BACKGROUND_NAVIGATION_MENU_COLOR = modelConfig.response.appColorScheme.slideMenu;
                    Constants.BACKGROUND_BUTTON_EDIT_COLOR = modelConfig.response.appColorScheme.appButtons;

                    Constants.TEXT_NAVIGATION_MENU_COLOR = modelConfig.response.appColorScheme.slideMenuColor;
                    Constants.TEXT_BUTTON_EDIT_COLOR = modelConfig.response.appColorScheme.appButtonsColor;
                    Constants.LOGO_PNG_PORTALS = modelConfig.response.design.logo;

                    Constants.PORTAL_ID = modelConfig.response.portalId;
                    Constants.PORTAL_NAME = modelConfig.response.portalCode;

                    StringBuilder strLangShort = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < modelConfig.response.design.langs.size(); i++) {
                    strLangShort.append(modelConfig.response.design.langs.get(i)).append(",");
                }
```

Model создавал через ConverterGson Плагин Android studio

Вопрос

> Как правильно создать модель или Какие настройки сделать в Retrofit,
>   чтобы программа игнорировала ошибку. И если приходит пустой langs то
>   Модель все равно собралась.

---

GSON Конвертер Android studio создает модель так без Map

```
public static class DesignBean {
            @SerializedName("logo") public String logo;
            @SerializedName("favicon") public String favicon;
            @SerializedName("langs") public LangsBean langs;
            @SerializedName("certificate") public String certificate;

            public static class LangsBean {
                @SerializedName("logo-en") public String logoen;
                @SerializedName("logo-ar") public String logoar;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Гляньте плиз еще раз. Оптимизировал вопрос. Думаю теперь ясно что требуется.

Comment: Попробуйте для langs использовать тип Map<String, String>

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Попробовал. В итоге программа не вылетает со 2 запросом. С 1 запросом я получаю null null.

`@SerializedName("langs") public Map<String, String> langs;` сделал правильно ведь?

Comment: Если заранее неизвестны поля объекта, то используется мапа-т.е. массив пар ключ-значение

Comment: У вас задача на лету меняется. Я запутался. Сформулируйте вопрос однозначно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Простите. Да я уже понял в чем проблема. Я беру значение из fori. указываю id вместа ключа в map. Поэтому и null null получаю. Модель заработала. Спасибо. Создайте ответ я закрою тему

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Я выше ссылку скинул. Вот так плагин собрал мне Pojo модель которая ломалась.

Вы сказали что знаете другой плагин. А можете дать название. Чтобы оно правильно собирало Pojo. Допустим через Map.

Comment: Я просто какой-то сайт юзал. Не думаю, что существуют такие, что МАР предлагали. Как им это можно было бы в алгоритм встроить-не могу представить